# Speeding up lookup of ranges of data from a collection

Tags: c#, linq, collections, linq-to-objects

Say I have a class

```
public class TimestampedTrackId
{
    private readonly int trackId;
    private readonly DateTime insertTime;
    public TimestampedTrackId(int trackId, DateTime insertTime)
    {
        this.trackId = trackId;
        this.insertTime = insertTime;
    }

    public int TrackId
    {
        get
        {
            return trackId;
        }
    }

    public DateTime InsertTime
    {
        get
        {
            return insertTime;
        }
    }
}
```

I have a large list of type `List<TimestampedTrackId>` and need to extract `TimestampedTrackId` instances from this list where the property InsertTime lies between a minimum and a maximum DateTime.

```
List<TimestampedTrackId> tracks; //Count=largeNumber
... 
tracks.Where(t=>t.InsertTime>min&&t.InsertTime<max)
```

A `List<T>` is obviously not the correct container for this task as it requires a search on every item to check if `InsertTime` lies between the min and max values.

So, I am assuming that part of speeding up this code would involve repackaging the list in a more suitable collection, but which collection?

Given the correct collection (which might be keyed), what query might I use to leverage maximum lookup speed?

Thanks in advance

Comment: How big is your collection (thousands/milions of records)?

Comment: The collection itself is not amazingly large... thousands... but I have thousands of these collections and need to lookup tens/hundreds of date ranges on each one, so speed is of the essence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you able to sort your list by `InsertTime`? If so, [`List<T>.BinarySearch`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ftfdbfx6.aspx) is your friend - provide an `IComparer<TimestampedTrackId>` which compares by `InsertTime`, and `BinarySearch` for `min` and `max`. (You'll need to create "dummy" `TimestampedTrackId` objects with an `InsertTime` values of `min` and `max` in order to search for them.)

If `BinarySearch` returns a negative value, you should take the bitwise complement (using the ~ operator) to find out the index where the value would be inserted. Also remember that if multiple items can have the same `InsertTime`, you'll need to work backwards from the `min` index and forwards from the `max` index to make sure you get the full range. Anyway, it'll still be a lot more efficient than a linear search. It's a bit more fiddly, admittedly :)

Answer (score 4):

A good solution might be to use a TreeMap, as that structure lends itself well to fetching a specific range of keys less than or greater than a given key.

.NET doesn't have one natively, but there's a good [implementation of one here](http://www.itu.dk/research/c5/).